# WebView PDF Page Jump

Tags: xcode

I have a WebView that displays a local pdf file.  The file is 230 pages long and loads fine etc.  I need a way for the user to jump to a specific page if I can.  For instance if they look at the table of contents of the pdf and they want to jump to page 120, they can do it?  Any ideas on getting this done?

Answer (score -1):

You're asking questions about using the Cocoa Touch APIs in the iPhone SDK, but you're tagging them "Xcode."  Xcode is the development **tool**, not the platform or the API; you will probably find a better audience for your questions if you add the "iphone-sdk" or "cocoa-touch" tags.